# Accessing a database from stored procedure created in another database in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have created a stored procedure in one of the MySQL databases say 'db_name'. Now in that stored procedure I am executing the following SQL query(for fetching the size of specific table in MB) which accesses the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database of MySQL.

```
SELECT ROUND(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024),2) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name';
```

The above query does not yields any results. May be because stored procedure created in one database is trying to access the tables in anoher database or schema.

Does anybody have idea how to successfully execute the above query in stored procedure or any alternate way?

Comment: Seems like the user that is running the store procedure does not have privileges to access the 'table_name' within 'db_name'. INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a virtual database that has info on all the databases accessible to the current user.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav. But I have installed the MySQL server on my local machine with default 'root' user and no password. So with this user I have access to all the databases and full privileges.

Comment: Can you show the procedure?

Comment: Sorry guys. My silly mistake.

SP script earlier:

*CREATE PROCEDURE TableSizes`(IN db_name INTEGER)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `TableSizes`(table_1) VALUES ( (SELECT DATA_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_1' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = db_name ));
END*

SP script after:

*CREATE PROCEDURE TableSizes`(IN db_name VARCHAR(20)) 
BEGIN 
 INSERT ....
END*

Here I changed IN parameter from INTEGER to VARCHAR(20) as I was to pass string value to SP. This silly mistake I only noticed when Devart asked me to provide the stored procedure code. Thanks to all of you once again.